# Uploading image with paperclip using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm trying to make image upload using form_tag and save it with paperclip gem. I'm stuck at the very beginning.

1) I've created model Image like this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "512x512>", :thumb => "128x128>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
                                :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                                :size => { :in => 0..512.kilobytes }
end
```

2) Made a migration like this:

```
class AddFileToImageModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :images, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :images, :avatar
  end
end
```

3) Made form in view:

```
<%= form_tag '/index_page/submitImage', multipart: true } do %>
    <%=file_field_tag( :avatar, class: 'image_file_input' )%>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit image', class: 'button large'%>
<%end%>
```

4) Made POST handler for this form like this:

```
image = Image.new( )
image.avatar = params[ :avatar ]
if ( image.save )
    flash[ :success ] = "image saved"
else
    flash[ :error ] = "Image upload failed!"
end
redirect_to index_page_path
```

5) When I select file in the form and press "submit image" button I get line "image.save" failed. Log content is the following:

```
Started POST "/index_page/submitImage" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-26 23:10:08 +0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#submitImage as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ufwOW9OcNcrBISGdEfwixmEonszIKNAtBlc4AqvK5OY=", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5fdea98 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131226-4639-11qvysd>, @original_filename="back.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"back.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "commit"=>"Submit image"}
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/index_page/index
```

Database does contain all migrations including paperclip fields. What do I miss?

Comment: Are you using `Rails 3` or `4`?

Comment: I use Rails 4. I just noticed image = Image.new() followed by image.save results in false regardless of assigning image.avatar anything.

Comment: Add your `controller code` as well.

Comment: Controller code is provided at step 4). Should I paste all the file instead of particular POST handler?

Comment: Ok my guess is: Did you `permit` :avatar: in your image_params?. See: `controller section` for `Rails 4`: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: I checked that! But I do not fully understand that. 'image.save' doesn't work even if I don't assign 'image.avatar' anything. E.i. couple of lines "i=Image.new()" "i.save" fails without dealing with 'params' in any way.

Comment: try to puts `image.errors.full_messages` in console.

Answer (score 0):

Use bang method of save to figure out the exact error

```
image.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the fact that there was no

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

in Gemfile. After including it works.